# Subset and Basis Question

Tags: linear-algebra

If $Q ={(−2,0,1),(5,−2,1),(11,7,−5),(−1,4, −2),(2, −3,1)}$ How do you find a Subset of Q which is also a basis for $R^3.$

Comment: A basis is a spanning set and a linearly independent set.  There's a theorem that states that if $V$ is a vector space is know to have dimension $n$, any linearly independent set of $n$ vectors is a basis of that space.  Thus, just find three linearly independent vectors among $Q$.  Are you blocked at that step, too ?

Comment: Yes, can I get a hint on finding the three independent vectors.

Comment: Hint:  Start with the first two.  Are they dependent or not?  If they are, look at #1 and #3 and so on.  If #1 and #2 are independent, is #3 a linear combination of them?  is #4? and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Row-reduce the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{
-2&5&11&-1&2\\
0&-2&7&4&-3\\
1&1&-5&-2&1
}
$$
The columns corresponding to the pivots form a basis of $\Bbb R^3$.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you're ok with an quite naive approach.  You need to find three independent vectors from $Q$.

Start with a non-null vector $\mathbf v_1 \in Q$.

Then select a non-null vector $\mathbf v_2 \in Q$ such that the equation $\mathbf v_2 = t \cdot \mathbf v_1$ has no solutions in $t$.  By decomposing into $x$, $y$ and $z$, the equation correspond to the system of equations :

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\mathbf v_2^x = t \cdot \mathbf v_1^x\\
\mathbf v_2^y = t \cdot \mathbf v_1^y\\
\mathbf v_2^z = t \cdot \mathbf v_1^z\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Lastly, select a non-null vector $\mathbf v_3 \in Q$ such that the equation $\mathbf v_3 = t \cdot \mathbf v_1 + s \cdot \mathbf v_2$ has no solution in $(t,s)$.  Again, you'll end up with a system of equations.  This time it's trickier to guess in advance $v_3$, as there are two parameters to take into account, but since $Q$ is small, you can try them all.